# VS2015 missing Auto-sync wwwroot/lib/ _references.js entries

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

So I am trying to connect up my Jasmine unit tests in a VS2015 web project with the resharper test runner and thought I would use the Auto-generate _references.js file to save me having to type the references in each test spec. The Auto-synced _references.js file doesn't however include any javascript dependencies from the wwwroot/lib folder. Bower is definitely copying them to that folder correctly, but the synchronization is ignoring that directory. I thought the references generation might scan the web project looking for .js files to reference but it seems to have missed a swathe of them.

[According to Mads Kristensen](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs):

> Whenever a .js file is added, renamed, moved or deleted, the _references.js file is automatically updated to reflect the changes.

This doesn't seem to be happening with .js files in wwwroot/lib. Is this on purpose? Do I have to turn auto-sync off and do it manually?